# Apache Nifi multiple processor to same relationship

Tags: azure, apache-nifi

As shown in the image below, I have added 2 processors to same relationship of another processor, it distributes the flow files equally into both the tail processors. Is it the expected behavior? if yes, then on what basis the partition is done?

[image: exampe image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending the same relationship to multiple processors does not partition the flow files, it sends all of them to both relationships. You typically do this when you want to the send the same data to multiple destinations (i.e. HDFS and Kafka for example).

If you want to improve the concurrency of PutAzureBlobStorage, then you would have one instance of the processor and increase the concurrent tasks in the scheduling tab of the processor.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thank you for your response. In the real scenario, there are other processors between ConsumeAzureEventHub and PutAzureBlobStorage. Sometimes the traffic from eventhub becomes so high and the queue of the intermediate processors becomes full. I have increased the concurrency as suggested and also to increase the queue size, but still facing the same issue. Is there any way to use partitions or auto-scaling in Nifi ?

Comment: Or we can have a `DistributeLoad` processor. That will also work, right? @BryanBende

Comment: Exactly. That's what I was looking for. Meanwhile I created my own processor called Partitioner for the same purpose. I am going use DistributeLoad now. Thanks a lot Bryan.

Comment: If you want to distribute the load across a cluster there are several technics using remote process groups or kafka, take a look at: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/16120/how-do-i-distribute-data-across-a-nifi-cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

I you want to distribute the load across a NiFi cluster, there are different approaches:

- Use Kafka to send messages (tasks) across the cluster.
- Use Site-2-Site.
- Push data using a processor who listen for incoming connections (HandleHttpRequest, ListenSyslog, andListenUDP) and a load balancer.

More information:
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/16120/how-do-i-distribute-data-across-a-nifi-cluster.html